# How do you cancel or unsubscribe before continuing with next in Observables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscription

I am very new with Rxjs/Observables and it really starts to bother me. I have used an Observable to go through methods and make sure that they get called (using next() function) one by one after each one is finished. So, how do you cancel the entire subscription after maybe lets say the second of all 5 next calls has issues with some data? Below is a simplified example code for you to understand the situation.

I am importing the following data:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

In the constructor I prepare my Observable:

```
this.myObservable = new Observable( observer => {
  observer.next( this.funcOne(observer) );
  observer.next( this.funcTwo(observer) );
  observer.next( this.funcThr(observer) );
  observer.next( this.funcFor(observer) );
  observer.complete();
} );
```

And (below) using the "subscribe()" method, I start the subscription:

```
this.subscription = this.myObservable.subscribe( x => {
  if( x === -1 )
    this.subscription.unsubscribe(); 
    // I was thinking to unsubscribe here, but that doesn't work. 
    // I get a message saying: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
  else
    this.doSomethingElse(x)
} )
```

How do I stop with everything completely by canceling or unsubscribing from the subscription? Hope that my question is clear and thank you for taking your time to read my frustration.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not really understand your use of streams, one way to cancel a subscription is to keep a Subject of boolean type and use takeUntil ( or pipe(takeUntil) depending on your version of rxjs ) and when you want to stop the subscription you can do a .next(true) on that Subject. That will end the subscription. 
Example:

```
private destroy$ = new Subject();
...
this.subscription = this.myObservable.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe( x => {
  if( x === -1 )
    this.destroy$.next(true); 
    // I was thinking to unsubscribe here, but that doesn't work. 
    // I get a message saying: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
  else
    this.doSomethingElse(x)
} )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html for more info

Comment: Thanks for the help Andrei, but I see that takeUntil is being used in timer and I don't use it. Could you help me with writing an example code for me as well?

Comment: Could you make an es6 code instead? I am new with Typescript and the way you provide Subject as type. I am using Rxjs 6+ and I hope that you can forgive me for asking too much of help here.

Comment: Thank you Andrei! I will be testing it out right now and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183860/discussion-between-xarialon-and-andrei-dumitrescu-tudor).